# Linker error when using class declarations from header files

Tags: c++, oop

I'm setting up a class in a file called "initialize.cpp" and adding a declaration in "Engine.h". When i try to use that class in Main, it gives me a linker error for each function being used.

```
unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl Application::run(void)" (?run@Application@@QEAAHXZ) referenced in function main

unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl Application::loop(void)" (?loop@Application@@QEAAHXZ) referenced in function main

unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl Application::termination(void)" (?termination@Application@@QEAAHXZ) referenced in function main
```

here is initialize.cpp

```
#include<GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

class Application {
public:
    int run() {
        /* Initialize the library */
        if (!glfwInit())
            return -1;

        /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
        window = glfwCreateWindow(1600, 900, "OpenGL Window", NULL, NULL);
        if (!window)
        {
            glfwTerminate();
            return -1;
        }

        /* Make the window's context current */
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        
        return 0;
    }

    void loop() {
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        {
            /* Render here */
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            /* Swap front and back buffers */
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);

            /* Poll for and process events */
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    int termination() {
        glfwTerminate();

        return 0;
    } 
private:
    GLFWwindow* window;
};
```

and here is the header file

```
#pragma once

class Application {
public:
    int run();

    int loop();

    int termination();
private:
};
```

and main

```
#include "Engine/Engine.h"

int main()
{
    Application application;

    application.run();
    application.loop();
    application.termination();

    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that I'm still very new to C++ and I'm sorry if I just overlooked something stupid, but it's always stupid mistakes that make us learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> here is initialize.cpp
>
> ```
> #include<GL/glew.h>
> #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
>
> class Application {
> public:
>   int run() {
>       /* Initialize the library */
>       if (!glfwInit())
>           return -1;
>   //...
> ```

This is not how you implement the member functions of a class. What this does is define a completely different `class Application` with all its member functions inlined and inaccessible to other `.cpp` files, while `main.cpp` only sees the `class Application` declared in the header, whose member functions are nowhere implemented.

Assuming `class Application` is declared in header `initialize.h`, change `initialize.cpp` as follows, instead.

```
#include<GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "initialize.h"

int Application::run() {
  /* Initialize the library */
  if (!glfwInit())
      return -1;
//...
  return 0;
}

void Application::loop() {
//...
}

int Application::termination() {
//...
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for letting me know that and solving my problem!